# Php Carbon custom time range and judge whether it expires

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

description：

> I need to get the date from the current date to the next 5 days.
>   And need to customize the current time, and make some restrictions

start date：

> 2019-06-01

end date：

> 2019-06-05

Daily time period：

> 08 ~ 10
>   10 ~ 12
>   12 ~ 14
>   14 ~ 16
>   16 ~ 18
>   18 ~ 20

Example 1:

> If the current time is in the range of 2019-06-01 00:00 - 10:00

result：

```sh
array:2 [▼
  0 => [
    'date' => '2019-06-01',
    "weekstr":"Saturday",
    "subdate":"06-01"
    'timelist' => [
        [
            'period'    => '08 ~ 10', 
            'starthour' => '08',
            'endhour'   => '10',
            'expired'   => false
        ]
        [
            'period'    => '10 ~ 12', 
            'starthour' => '10',
            'endhour'   => '12',
            'expired'   => false
        ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => [
    'date' => '2019-06-02',
    "weekstr":"Saturday",
    "subdate":"06-01"
    'timelist' => [
        [
            'period'    => '08 ~ 10', 
            'starthour' => '08',
            'endhour'   => '10',
            'expire'    => false
        ]
        [
            'period'    => '10 ~ 12', 
            'starthour' => '10',
            'endhour'   => '12',
            'expire'    => false
        ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Example 2:

> If the current time is within the range of 2019-06-01 10:00 - 11:00

result：

```sh
array:2 [▼
  0 => [
    'date' => '2019-06-01',
    "weekstr":"Saturday",
    "subdate":"06-01"
    'timelist' => [
        [
            'period'    => '08 ~ 10', 
            'starthour' => '08',
            'endhour'   => '10',
            'expire'    => true //Has passed 08:00 - 10:00 has expired, displayed as true
        ]
        [
            'period'    => '10 ~ 12', 
            'starthour' => '10',
            'endhour'   => '12',
            'expire'    => false
        ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => [
    'date' => '2019-06-02',
    "weekstr":"Saturday",
    "subdate":"06-01"
    'timelist' => [
        [
            'period'    => '08 ~ 10', 
            'starthour' => '08',
            'endhour'   => '10',
            'expired'   => false
        ]
        [
            'period'    => '10 ~ 12', 
            'starthour' => '10',
            'endhour'   => '12',
            'expired'   => false
        ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

> summary: To achieve this function, I don't have a good idea at present. I want to ask for help and give me some ideas and methods, or I can give some sample code for my reference. Thank you.

#### Latest situation

- According to the prompt given by Fabián Montero Rodríguez, I have implemented the date processing, but there is no good idea to deal with the time period.

code:

```php
$start_date   = Carbon::now();
$end_date     = Carbon::now()->addDays(2);
$date_periods = CarbonPeriod::create($start_date, $end_date);
$dates = [];
foreach ($date_periods as $key => $date){
    $dates[$key]['date']    = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $dates[$key]['week']    = $date->localeDayOfWeek;
    $dates[$key]['subdate'] = $date->format('m-d');
}
dd($dates);
```

result:

```sh
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "date" => "2019-05-31"
    "week" => "Friday"
    "subdate" => "05-31"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "date" => "2019-06-01"
    "week" => "Saturday"
    "subdate" => "06-01"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "date" => "2019-06-02"
    "week" => "Sunday"
    "subdate" => "06-02"
  ]
]
```

#### Current problem

> The date range has been thought of, but the time range in each date timelist still has no good ideas to deal with, request help me

Comment: so you are trying to create a date range with time

Comment: @Manojkiran.A Yes, there are two parts, date range and time range. Can you help me?

Comment: check the answer and tell me if anything need to ne changed

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't clearly understand your requirement I have separate route in web.php

Caution: be careful with setting timezones. Setting the wrong timezone in `config/app.php` may result in a big in `expired` parameter.

And written a Closure function:

```
    Route::any('/carbonintervaltest/', function () {
    $startDate   = Carbon::now();
    $endDate     = Carbon::now()->addDays(2);
    $dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, $endDate);

    $dates = [];
    foreach ($dateRange as $dateKey =>  $date) {
        $dates[$dateKey]['date']    = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        $dates[$dateKey]['week']    = $date->localeDayOfWeek;
        $dates[$dateKey]['subdate'] = $date->format('m-d');
        $dates[$dateKey]['timelist'] = generateTime($date);
    }
    dd($dates);
});
function generateTime(Carbon $date)
{
    $startOfDay = $date->startOfDay();

    $eightTen = generateTwoHoursDifference($startOfDay, 8);

    $eightTenPeriod = getPeriod($eightTen);
    $tenTwelve = generateTwoHoursDifference($startOfDay, 10);
    $tenTwelvePeriod = getPeriod($tenTwelve);
    $totalTime = [$eightTenPeriod,$tenTwelvePeriod];
    return $totalTime;
}
function getPeriod(array $arrayObCarbonObj)
{
    foreach ($arrayObCarbonObj as $singleCarbonObj) {
        $eachHour[] = $singleCarbonObj->format('H');
    }
    $period = implode(' ~ ', $eachHour);
    $starthour = $eachHour[0];
    $endhour = $eachHour[1];
    $expired = !$arrayObCarbonObj['timeTwo']->isFuture();
    return   [
            'period'    => $period,
            'starthour' => $starthour,
            'endhour'   => $endhour,
            'expired'   => $expired
    ];
}
function generateTwoHoursDifference(Carbon $date, int $start, int $increment = 2)
{
    $dateFirstObj = (new Carbon)->parse($date->toDateTimeString());
    $dateSecondtObj = (new Carbon)->parse($date->toDateTimeString());
    $firstTime = $dateFirstObj->addHours($start);
    $secondTime = $dateSecondtObj->addHours($start+$increment);
    $allTime = ['timeOne' => $firstTime , 'timeTwo' => $secondTime];
    return $allTime;
}
```

Import these classes in web.php:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
```

Paste the code at the top of the web.php file and **hit the route**

> **yourapp/carbonintervaltest**

So it will give the `dd` result if the result is What you are looking for.

If you are not clear about it, I have created a Gist for that and pasted the entire file.

If you are facing any issue kindly comment below

https://gist.github.com/ManojKiranA/993383025928c285c30db6418e10708b

Here is the dd result

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "date" => "2019-06-01"
    "week" => "Saturday"
    "subdate" => "06-01"
    "timelist" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "period" => "08 ~ 10"
        "starthour" => "08"
        "endhour" => "10"
        "expired" => true
      ]
      1 => array:4 [▼
        "period" => "10 ~ 12"
        "starthour" => "10"
        "endhour" => "12"
        "expired" => true
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "date" => "2019-06-02"
    "week" => "Sunday"
    "subdate" => "06-02"
    "timelist" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "period" => "08 ~ 10"
        "starthour" => "08"
        "endhour" => "10"
        "expired" => false
      ]
      1 => array:4 [▼
        "period" => "10 ~ 12"
        "starthour" => "10"
        "endhour" => "12"
        "expired" => false
      ]
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "date" => "2019-06-03"
    "week" => "Monday"
    "subdate" => "06-03"
    "timelist" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "period" => "08 ~ 10"
        "starthour" => "08"
        "endhour" => "10"
        "expired" => false
      ]
      1 => array:4 [▼
        "period" => "10 ~ 12"
        "starthour" => "10"
        "endhour" => "12"
        "expired" => false
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: I just got on the line, thank you very much, I tried to give an error.

Comment: Have you seen my gist

Comment: InvalidArgumentException
Trailing data

Comment: What time zone is set when you test?

Comment: my timeZone is asia calcutta

Comment: come to chat room  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194282/php-carbon

Comment: can you share the entire controller

Comment: [Error screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30326966/58747663-e994fd00-84a0-11e9-898b-3eb5eb68cce4.png)

Comment: wait i will try in the 5.5  i think the issue in the Carbon Library

Comment: I can't get in the chat room, I don't have enough reputation. Do you have other communication tools?

Comment: check now i have update the gist basen on the chat but set your timezone in `config/app.php`